# What might "interfere" with a DataTables AJAX scroll-bar in this way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I know that this must have something to do with the CSS (or perhaps JS) on "this old site," but I haven't quite put my finger on what to look at first.

Basically, I have an AJAX-sourced DataTable, but when I try to select the scroll-bar to move it up and down, it "sticks."  Doesn't move smoothly and show the record-number indicator ... as it does when I use the demos on the DataTables home page in the very same browser.  I *do* see AJAX requests being sent for other row-ranges (and being properly returned), but when I finally let go of the mostly non-sliding slider it pops right back up to the top again.

Does this description of symptoms "ring bells" with anyone out there?  As in: *"oh, yeah, this happened to me once, and I ..."*

Comment: It sounds like there's an handler bound to the scroll event which is taking some time to complete that's slowing everything down. However without seeing the code, this is a complete guess.

Comment: That's what I thought too, Roy.  But as I noted below, the entire(!) mis-behavior seems to have come down to one missing CSS (theme ...) file.  (This is an old application which still relies on themes that apparently the "uikit" people don't even support or distribute anymore.)  One thing's for sure about this programming biz ... "every day is interesting!"

Comment: Glad you got it working, but there's no need to add `[SOLVED]` to the title :) An answer, and accepting it (when the system allows) is perfectly adequate.

Comment: "Accepting it?"  Never saw that in SO.  Isn't my self-answer "accepted?"

Answer (score 0):

*"Well, isn't CSS always **very** strange ..."*

Apparently, *one(!)* "uikit theme CSS-file" was not being loaded correctly, and everything just went downhill from there.  When I forced that file to be loaded, suddenly the DataTable began to work, as did quite a number of other things.

Of course, "I knew that it really wasn't a DataTables problem to begin with," but it's really quite remarkable just how *disruptive* the absence of a single CSS file turned out to be!

Comment: its not just the absence of a *css* file, its the absence of any file, or paragraph, or line, or even a character. That makes your program to not work as expected or not work at all

Comment: Well, the only thing that was `404`ing was ... a CSS file.  (Now, probably a very fundamental one since it's a "theme.")  When I found a copy and forced it to be in the right place, suddenly the screen looked very different *and* the  DataTable started working.  I was frankly quite surprised to see how profoundly this had been affecting the DataTable.  I was primed to look for JavaScript interference ... "this old page in this old app" previously used DataTables but didn't use AJAX.  But the missing CSS file superficially appears to be "it."  Go figger ... ***:-)***